# Anyone know how to install a new graphics card on the Thinkpad T400?

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, opengl

Is that even possible?

I know that it's hard to install new hardware on laptops, but it would be doable on a Thinkpad.

The reason why I want a new graphics card is because the one I have is not programmable. At least, it does not behave the way it does on machines with the appropriate graphics card.

Anyway, any idea on how to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laptop graphics cards are usually built directly into the motherboard and cannot be upgraded with the exception of a few that have a [MXM interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module) - Sort of like PCI Express for laptops.

I have searched a few databases and I cannot find your laptop listed which I believe means that it cannot be upgraded.

[Here is a guide](http://www.mxm-upgrade.com/Check.html) to tell if yours can, but it requires some work that could void your warranty!

Also, a way to tell is often to look at the model line - if you see other laptops that are very similar but have different display adapters, it usually means that it is swappable - for example, if there is a Thinkpad T400b.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ThinkWiki's page on the T400](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T400).  There's a link to the [Hardware Maintenance Manual](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-70069) that should describe how to do what you want to do, assuming it's possible.

The T400s use an [integrated Intel GPU](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Media_Accelerator_4500MHD); some models include a [switchable](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Switchable_Graphics) [ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3470](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ATI_Mobility_Radeon_HD_3470).  If yours does not include the optional ATI card, you may be able to add it in one of the MiniPCI-E slots.  The hardware manual will detail that process.

Answer (score 0):

My Lenovo Thinkpad T400 has a total of three Mini PCI-e Ports. Only one is used when I bought it.

I currently am using a Radeon HD card and it is possible, but to avoid conflicts you need to set the PCI-e card as default in BIOS and disable on board.